# Find xpath of element knowing a part of href attribute only selenium ide ui vision katalon recorder

Tags: selenium, xpath, ide, kantu, katalon

I need to detect via xpath an element (image with href) but i know a part of href only

This is the html

```
<a href="/mysite.com?id=123456"><img src="//user/banners/16/08/1614708.gif" alt="AAA" data-tip="BBB" currentitem="false" class="" width="468" height="60"></a>
```

I know the id 123456 (part of href)

I tried this xpath that recognize element with a part of href but working in text link only

```
xpath=//a[contains(@href, "123456")]
```

How can i detect the element using a part of href only ?

I need xpath only please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find xpath in html element using a part of href only katalon recorder, kantu, selenium ide, ui vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655194/find-xpath-in-html-element-using-a-part-of-href-only-katalon-recorder-kantu-se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get `/img` in `//a` where `href` attribute `contains()` or `ends-with()` your id
This is XPATH that you need. At least i would use this XPATH in this situation

```
//a[ends-with(@href, 'your-id-here')]/img
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expresions. Something like

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with (@name,'Tut')]")

or as you described

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@name,'sel')]").

Be awere of one thing, do not use double quotes, for the string you are searching as atribute value. Use a single quote like I previously described.