# Find xpath in html element using a part of href only katalon recorder, kantu, selenium ide, ui vision

Tags: selenium, xpath, ide, katalon-recorder, kantu

I need to detect via xpath an element (image with href) but i know a part of href only

This is the html

```
<a href="/play.php?video=123456">
<div class="video-splash" data-src="https://myimge-555888.jpg?md5=dfgdfsdgsowVf0QnDcAg&amp;expires=16018841600&amp;origin=103&amp;mid=0df2fd8d-85b1-47da-a371-489a7328ffb4">
<div class="video-time"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> <b>HD</b> 43:25</div>
</div>
</a>
```

I know the video 123456 (part of href)

video number change periodically

data-src change periodically

I tried these xpaths but in this case do not work

```
xpath=//a[contains(@href, "123456")]

xpath=//a[ends-with(@href, '123456')]/img

xpath=//a[contains(@href, '123456')]/img
```

How can i detect the element using a part of href only ?

I need a xpath only that can detect the element please.

Need a generic xpath because some attributes are dynamic `video=???` and `data-src=???` and `<b>???</b> ??? </div>`

??? dynamic values that change always, i need to detect it via video number.

I add more html code

```
<div>

<h2 class="page-h2">
Performer <b>username</b> — Recent Recordings
</h2>
<div class="video-thumb">
<a href="/play.php?video=550420">
<div class="video-splash" data-src="https://v02.frontgross.com/username/2020-04-25,29-59.jpg?md5=BV75Ney9jydwiZgdITkjSg&expires=2705442700&origin=205&mid=5e5c77ca-f750-49ed-9527-725754b972f2">
<div class="video-time"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> <b>HD</b> 59:25</div>
</div>
</a>
<div class="video-info">
<div>
<a href="/?performer=username"><b>username</b></a>
</div>
<div class="video-info-sub"><span class="video-views">22.5K views</span> • 2020-04-25 29:59</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="video-thumb">
<a href="/play.php?video=529055">
<div class="video-splash" data-src="https://v02.frontgross.com/username/2020-04-25,02-00.jpg?md5=d2GDbtiHuKT-by9A9qcMIA&expires=2705442700&origin=205&mid=5e5c77ca-f750-49ed-9527-725754b972f2">
<div class="video-time"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> <b>HD</b> 45:25</div>
</div>
</a>
<div class="video-info">
<div>
<a href="/?performer=username"><b>username</b></a>
</div>
<div class="video-info-sub"><span class="video-views">20.0K views</span> • 2020-04-25 02:00</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="video-thumb">
<a href="/play.php?video=529725">
<div class="video-splash" data-src="https://v02.frontgross.com/username/2020-04-24,29-55.jpg?md5=RrwtygDUT_zxTPf4mC2KAw&expires=2705442700&origin=205&mid=5e5c77ca-f750-49ed-9527-725754b972f2">
<div class="video-time"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> <b>HD</b> 2:02:29</div>
</div>
</a>
<div class="video-info">
<div>
<a href="/?performer=username"><b>username</b></a>
</div>
<div class="video-info-sub"><span class="video-views">20.9K views</span> • 2020-04-24 29:55</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="video-thumb">
<a href="/play.php?video=527092">
<div class="video-splash" data-src="https://v02.frontgross.com/username/2020-04-25,22-00.jpg?md5=unQIgoVWLXy5cBH4sPVWUw&expires=2705442700&origin=205&mid=5e5c77ca-f750-49ed-9527-725754b972f2">
<div class="video-time"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> <b>HD</b> 20:52</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: //a[contains(@href, "/play.php?video=")] so the starting portion remains? Is there any other tags that are similar.

Comment: Tried and do not works

Comment: @arundeepchohan I add more html code, your solution do not work. Thanks

Comment: No Point! You won't be able to download :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
xpath=//div/a[@href='/play.php?video=123456']
```

Need to start xpath with //div/a

Other solutions do not works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Be aware of fact that you maybe need to navigate to your link, because I cant see more of your HTML so I do not now is it uniqe.

```
//*a[starts-with(@herf, 'sometext') and ends-with(@herf, '123456')]
```

Comment: There are error herf must be href. i tried it correct but do not work

Comment: I add more html code, your solution do not work. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: I can see you have multiple videos, do you know any thing specific related to video element that you want to use. e.g. duration, or maybe that part of link(which is dynamic I assume). .. One more thing i assume that your HTML does not have appropriate formats, it is not ordered by nodes.

Comment: I know video=XXXXXX, I want to detect element via video number but i can not find a xpath to detect video using video number. There are a large amount of video, and i have a list of video to open (video=XXXXXX).

Comment: If you know the number for video then why don use:
( "//a[@href='/play.php?video=" + videoString+"']")

where videoString is String variable

Comment: Never of these solution detect the video, seems the videos can not detected by href, i tried all solutions.